# How can make people write better question titles?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We have a lot of questions that have titles like "it doesn't work", "error when I do thing" etc.

Eg.

> "Error building program with program v1.18 and CLI v1.17"

Nice this includes version info, but it would be better for the titles to include the actual error.

I'm concerned that we will have a sea of similarly looking vague questions that people have to wade through whenever something doesn't work, to find a question that actually matches the error they are experiencing.

We can fix questions like these manually, but I wonder if we couldn't provide some guidance in the StackOverflow UI.

Eg:

> include the specific error in the title

or

> don't just say something didn't work, include the error in the title

or similar. **How we can we make question titles be more specific?** Or do others think vague question titles are not a problem?